# Apache POI scatter chart creation

Tags: java, excel, graph, charts, apache-poi

Currently generating a scatterplot using POI, however the chart comes out weird:
[image: charts]
The topleft one is generated using my code, the other one is made manually in Excel.
They are both of the type "scatter with straight lines and markers", the generated chart however shows curved lines for some reason. Another issue is that each of the data-points is listed separately in the legend as well as given another colour.

```
public void GenerateChart(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

    XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
    XSSFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

    XSSFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    XSSFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

    CellRangeAddress crXData = new CellRangeAddress(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 0, 0);
    CellRangeAddress crYData = new CellRangeAddress(1, sheet.getLastRowNum(), 1, 1);
    CellReference crTitle = new CellReference(0,1);
    Cell cell = sheet.getRow(crTitle.getRow()).getCell(crTitle.getCol());

    ChartDataSource<Number> dsXData = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, crXData);
    ChartDataSource<Number> dsYData = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, crYData);

    XSSFScatterChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();
    ScatterChartSeries seriesTitler = data.addSerie(dsXData, dsYData);

    seriesTitler.setTitle(cell.getStringCellValue());
    chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
}
```

Using Apache POI 3.17
Documentation [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/charts/XSSFScatterChartData.html) shows that `XSSFScatterChartData` and others are deprecated, and that I should be using `XDDFScatterChartData` instead. However I cannot figure out where to get the .jar to use this. I'm assuming it's in beta?

What I want to do is to generate something like the chart on the right of the image, the manually created one. Since POI allowing chart creation seems to be a relatively new thing, I haven't been able to find any clues. Anyone know the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are changed defaults for `Excel` charts in newer `Excel` versions.

There is a setting for smooth the line in scatter charts. `Apache poi` does not set this. But now in newer `Excel`versions this option defaults to true if it is not set.

Also there is a setting for vary the colors of each data point. Also `apache poi` does not set this. But now in newer `Excel`versions this option defaults to true if not set.

So we need setting both of those options to false as wanted:

```
...
  chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

  //set properties of first scatter chart data series to not smooth the line:
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(0)
   .addNewSmooth().setVal(false);

  //set properties of first scatter chart to not vary the colors:
  ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0)
   .addNewVaryColors().setVal(false);
...
```

Unfortunately the https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/ is **not** the POI API Documentation for the latest stable release but for the current  "Nightly Build". So for using the `XDDF` instead of `XSSF` one needs using the nightly builds which of course are **not** stable releases which should be used in productive code.

Comment: After turning off the vary colors option can we set the color of the markers in the series? I can only see an option to set the marker style not its color.