# Problem running official examples LineChars and ScatterChart with Apache POI 4.0

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

There's a problem with the [official](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/examples.html#xssf-only) examples [LineChart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/LineChart.java) and [ScatterChart](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ScatterChart.java) for Apache POI 4.0. They compile and run without errors, but the created Excel file cannot be opened stating that there is unreadable content. Excel 2010 & 2016 are giving the option to recover data from the workbook and after clickin' yes, this [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0Ien.png) appears. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new `XDDF` code lacks the setting the `axId`s in the `lineChart` and `scatterChart`.

In `/xl/charts/chart1.xml` this looks like:

```
<c:lineChart>
 ...
 <c:axId val="0"/>
 <c:axId val="1"/>
</c:lineChart>
```

for a line chart..

Do adding:

```
...
            XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.LINE, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            chart.plot(data);

            //setting the axis Ids to the LineChart
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(bottomAxis.getId());
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLineChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(leftAxis.getId());


            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-line-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
...
```

in `LineChart.java`

and

```
...
            XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.SCATTER, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

            data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            chart.plot(data);

            //setting the axis Ids to the ScatterChart
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(bottomAxis.getId());
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).addNewAxId().setVal(leftAxis.getId());


            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-scatter-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }

...
```

in `ScatterChart.java`

and it will work.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you explain why this setting is so important? To me, it looks like redundant as there is alredy `XDDFChartData data = chart.createData(ChartTypes.SCATTER, bottomAxis, leftAxis);`. Note that I've been playing with settings for smoothing and varying colors. Smoothing is enabled by default but it can be switched off. No luck with varying colors. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116862/apache-poi-scatter-chart-creation) post for info about that.

Comment: @trimtosize: The new `XDDF` code of `apache poi` is simply buggy. That's it.

Comment: Does that mean that setting axis ids can be considered as a bug and that POI should have set it automatically under the hood of the `createData` method?

Comment: @trimtosize: Yes, because the `XSSFChart` code up to `apache poi` version 3.17 had done this properly.