# Setting the color of an Excel sheet scatter chart marker icon with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, scatter-plot

The [scatter chart example included with Apache POI](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/ScatterChart.java) shows how to set the color of a line (that connects markers in a series), but I cannot figure out how to set the color of a marker for a series. I see that I can change the marker icon (with `setMarkerStyle` ([javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xddf/usermodel/chart/XDDFScatterChartData.Series.html#setMarkerStyle-org.apache.poi.xddf.usermodel.chart.MarkerStyle-)), but that does not appear to have editable color properties).

From [a previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50117677/475329) I suspect that it will be necessary to disable the vary colors configuration, but I still do not know how to set the colors after that step (if the following line is even necessary).

`((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0)
   .addNewVaryColors().setVal(false);`

How can I specify the marker icon colors in the example below?

```
public class ScatterChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");
            final int NUM_OF_ROWS = 3;
            final int NUM_OF_COLUMNS = 10;

            // Create a row and put some cells in it. Rows are 0 based.
            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < NUM_OF_ROWS; rowIndex++) {
                row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex);
                for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_OF_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
                    cell = row.createCell((short) colIndex);
                    cell.setCellValue(colIndex * (rowIndex + 1.0));
                }
            }

            XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 10, 15);

            XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
            XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
            legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.TOP_RIGHT);

            XDDFValueAxis bottomAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            bottomAxis.setTitle("x"); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010765
            XDDFValueAxis leftAxis = chart.createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
            leftAxis.setTitle("f(x)");
            leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

            XDDFDataSource<Double> xs = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 0, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys1 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));
            XDDFNumericalDataSource<Double> ys2 = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(2, 2, 0, NUM_OF_COLUMNS - 1));


            XDDFScatterChartData data = (XDDFScatterChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.SCATTER, bottomAxis, leftAxis);
            XDDFScatterChartData.Series series1 = (XDDFScatterChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
            series1.setTitle("2x", null); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855842
            series1.setSmooth(false); // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636138
            XDDFScatterChartData.Series series2 = (XDDFScatterChartData.Series) data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
            series2.setTitle("3x", null);
            chart.plot(data);

            solidLineSeries(data, 0, PresetColor.CHARTREUSE);
            solidLineSeries(data, 1, PresetColor.TURQUOISE);

            // Write the output to a file
            try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("ooxml-scatter-chart.xlsx")) {
                wb.write(fileOut);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void solidLineSeries(XDDFChartData data, int index, PresetColor color) {
        XDDFSolidFillProperties fill = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(color));
        XDDFLineProperties line = new XDDFLineProperties();
        line.setFillProperties(fill);
        XDDFChartData.Series series = data.getSeries().get(index);
        XDDFShapeProperties properties = series.getShapeProperties();
        if (properties == null) {
            properties = new XDDFShapeProperties();
        }
        properties.setLineProperties(line);
        series.setShapeProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous question you linked is from May 2018 and is about the pure `XSSFChart` stuff from `apache poi` upto version `3.17`. This is outdated since `apache poi 4.0.0` introduced the new `XDDF` stuff.

Nevertheless setting the marker color is not supported until now using only the high level `XDDF` classes. The marker has shape properties having fill properties of the same kind as the series itself. So we can use `XDDFSolidFillProperties` and `XDDFShapeProperties` as for the line settings. But to get the marker, we need using the low level underlying `ooxml-schemas-1.4` beans.

Example:

```
...
series2.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.DIAMOND);
series2.setMarkerSize((short)15);
XDDFSolidFillProperties fillMarker = new XDDFSolidFillProperties(XDDFColor.from(new byte[]{(byte)0xFF, (byte)0xFF, 0x00}));
XDDFShapeProperties propertiesMarker = new XDDFShapeProperties();
propertiesMarker.setFillProperties(fillMarker);
chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray(1).getMarker()
     .addNewSpPr().set(propertiesMarker.getXmlObject());
...
```

Comment: Works great but the marker border colors are still set to the default coloring. Is it a similar process to change the border color?

Comment: Yup ok I got it. `XDDFNoFillProperties noFill = new XDDFNoFillProperties();` `XDDFShapeProperties propertiesMarker = new XDDFShapeProperties();` `propertiesMarker.setFillProperties(fillMarker);`
`XDDFLineProperties lineProperties = new XDDFLineProperties();`
`lineProperties.setFillProperties(noFill);`
`propertiesMarker.setLineProperties(lineProperties);`